# When to return IOrderedEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, semantics, iorderedenumerable

Should `IOrderedEnumerable` be used as a return type purely for semantic value?

For example, when consuming a model in the presentation layer, how can we know whether the collection requires ordering or is already ordered?

What about in the case that a repository wraps a stored procedure with an `ORDER BY` clause. Should the repository return `IOrderedEnumerable`? And how would that be achieved?

Comment: see this possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829487/c-is-it-possible-to-return-an-iorderedenumerablet or 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783830/can-it-be-advantageous-for-a-method-to-return-iorderedenumerablet-instead-of-i?rq=1

Comment: Re: @nawfal I think you're right, though I believe [the guidance on meta says to close the other questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/184684) iff this question has better discussion. It certainly has _more_, but your first possible dupe has [a good Skeet answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/829515/1028230) and the second's [answer is succinct and helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1783907/1028230). So you got me. `;^D`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't think it would be a good idea:

> Should IOrderedEnumerable be used as a return type purely for semantic value?
>
> For example, when consuming a model in the presentation layer, how can we know whether the collection requires ordering or is already ordered?

What is the point in knowing that a sequence is ordered if you don't know by which key it is ordered? The point of the `IOrderedEnumerable` interface is to be able to add a secondary sort criteria, which doesn't make much sense if you don't know what is the primary criteria.

> What about in the case that a repository wraps a stored procedure with an ORDER BY clause. Should the repository return IOrderedEnumerable? And how would that be achieved?

This doesn't make sense. As I already said, `IOrderedEnumerable` is used to add a secondary sort criteria, but when the data is returned by the stored procedure, it is already sorted and it's too late to add a secondary sort criteria. All you can do is re-sort it completely, so calling `ThenBy` on the result wouldn't have the expected effect.

Comment: It's not necessarily too late to add secondary sort criteria. It is very hard - perhaps to the point of impossibility - to do so in a very general way, but it would be possible for a method that knew it would always order on field `A` to offer `CreateOrderedEnumerable()` based on that knowledge (which `ThenBy` calls into). Much trickier in the more general case though, and probably not actually very useful.

Comment: "_if you don't know by which key it is ordered_" Then what's the "right" return value for an ordered collection that communicates that sorting? Could you make the same argument against returning `List<T>`, eg? `IEnumerable` seems to maintain the subtype it's assigned to (`IEnumerable<string> e2 = (IEnumerable<string>)new string[] { b, a, c };` has a `GetType()` of `System.String[]`, eg). If you're returning something ordered (esp [ordered but not materialized](https://tech-mint.com/programming-languages/csharp/ienumerable-iqueryable-how-query-works/#Deferred_execution)), what's The Right Way?

Comment: @ruffin I completely agree. You can never have complete semantics, as that is defined by the owner of the object. I can imagine lots of situations in which e.g. a view model may have a list of items already ordered 'the right way'. It is really nobody else's business to ask what 'the right way' is, the important thing by-contract is, that the task of ordering has already been done. "You can render these the way they are."

Answer (score 12):

As Thomas points out, knowing that an object is an `IOrderedEnumerable` tells us only that it's been ordered in some way, not that it's been ordered in a way that we will want to maintain.

It's also worth noting that the return type will influence overrides and compile-ability, but not runtime checks:

```
private static IOrderedEnumerable<int> ReturnOrdered(){return new int[]{1,2,3}.OrderBy(x => x);}
private static IEnumerable<int> ReturnOrderUnknown(){return ReturnOrdered();}//same object, diff return type.
private static void UseEnumerable(IEnumerable<int> col){Console.WriteLine("Unordered");}
private static void UseEnumerable(IOrderedEnumerable<int> col){Console.WriteLine("Ordered");}
private static void ExamineEnumerable(IEnumerable<int> col)
{
  if(col is IOrderedEnumerable<int>)
    Console.WriteLine("Enumerable is ordered");
  else
    Console.WriteLine("Enumerable is unordered");
}
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //Demonstrate compile-time loses info from return types
  //if variable can take either:
  var orderUnknown = ReturnOrderUnknown();
  UseEnumerable(orderUnknown);//"Unordered";
  orderUnknown = ReturnOrdered();
  UseEnumerable(orderUnknown);//"Unordered"
  //Demonstate this wasn't a bug in the overload selection:
  UseEnumerable(ReturnOrdered());//"Ordered"'
  //Demonstrate run-time will see "deeper" than the return type anyway:
  ExamineEnumerable(ReturnOrderUnknown());//Enumerable is ordered.
}
```

Because of this, if you have a case where there could be either `IEnumerable<T>` or `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` returned to the caller depending on circumstance, the variable will be typed as `IEnumerable<T>` and the information from the return type lost. Meanwhile, no matter what the return type, the caller will be able to determine if the type is really `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.

Either way, return type didn't really matter.

The trade-off with return types are between utility to the caller vs flexibility to the callee.

Consider a method that currently ends with `return currentResults.ToList()`. The following return types are possible:

1. `List<T>`
2. `IList<T>`
3. `ICollection<T>`
4. `IEnumerable<T>`
5. `IList`
6. `ICollection`
7. `IEnumerable`
8. `object`

Let's exclude object and the non-generic types right now as unlikely to be useful (in cases where they would be useful, they are probably no-brainer decisions to use). This leaves:

1. `List<T>`
2. `IList<T>`
3. `ICollection<T>`
4. `IEnumerable<T>`

The higher up the list we go, the more convenience we give the caller to make use of the functionality exposed by that type, that is not exposed by the type below. The lower down the list we go, the more flexibility we give to the callee to change the implementation in the future. Ideally therefore, we want to go as high up the list as makes sense in the context of the method's purpose (to expose useful functionality to the caller, and reduce cases where new collections are created to offer functionality we were already offering) but no higher (to allow for future changes).

So, back to our case where we have an `IOrderedEnumerable<TElement>` that we can return as either an `IOrderedEnumerable<TElement>` or an `IEnumerable<T>` (or `IEnumerable` or `object`).

The question is, is the fact that this is an `IOrderedEnumerable` inherently related to the purpose of the method, or is it merely an implementation artefact?

If we had a method `ReturnProducts` that happened to order by price to as part of the implementation of removing cases where the same product was offered twice for different prices, then it should return `IEnumerable<Product>`, because callers shouldn't care that it's ordered, and certainly shouldn't depend upon it.

If we had a method `ReturnProductsOrderedByPrice` where the ordering was part of its purpose, then we should return `IOrderedEnumerable<Product>`, because this relates more closely to its purpose, and may reasonably expect that calling `CreateOrderedEnumerable`, `ThenBy` or `ThenByDescending` on it (the only things this really offers) and not have this broken by a subsequent change to the implementation.

Edit: I missed the second part of this.

> What about in the case that a repository wraps a stored procedure with
>   an ORDER BY clause. Should the repository return IOrderedEnumerable?
>   And how would that be achieved?

That is quite a good idea when possible (or perhaps `IOrderedQueryable<T>`). However, it's not simple.

First, you have to be sure that nothing subsequent to the `ORDER BY` could have undone the ordering, this may not be trivial.

Secondly, you have to not undo this ordering in a call to `CreateOrderedEnumerable<TKey>()`.

For example, if elements with fields `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` are being returned from something that used `ORDER BY A DESCENDING, B` resulting in the return of a type called `MyOrderedEnumerable<El>` that implements `IOrderedEnumerable<El>`. Then, the fact that `A` and `B` are the fields that were ordered on must be stored. A call to `CreateOrderedEnumerable(e => e.D, Comparer<int>.Default, false)` (which is also what `ThenBy` and `ThenByDescending` call into) must take groups of elements that compare equally for `A` and `B`, by the same rules for which they were returned by the database (matching collations between databases and .NET can be hard), and only within those groups must it then order according to `cmp.Compare(e0.D, e1.D)`.

If you could do that, it could be very useful, and it would totally be appropriate that the return type were `IOrderedEnumerable` if `ORDER BY` clauses would be present on all queries used by all calls.

Otherwise, `IOrderedEnumerable` would be a lie - since you couldn't fulfil the contract it offers - and it would be less than useless.

Answer (score 0):

IMO `IOrderedEnumerable` and an `IOrderedCollection` could have been very useful for high level operations that will ie work on lists and arrays but not on sets, however somehow List does not inherit it so it lost that purpose. It is now only useful for the kind of thinkgs you showed in the second part of your question (order by etc)